# Why i can't show/hide Html TR using jquery?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, html, show-hide

I have the following `TR` in HTML and i using JQuery

```
<tr class="RowDiv" id="tempTR" runat="server" visible="false">                    <td>
                    <div class="LabelDiv">
                        <div class="dfltTxtBld">
                            ID<span class="reqChar" runat="server" id="Span1" visible="false">
                                *</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="InputDiv">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="txtField" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="Div1" runat="server">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

and in javascript code i called the following method to hide it

```
$('#<%= tempTR.ClientID %>').hide();
```

but always it doesn't affected even i try to make it hidden and then show it also not work .. i try to hide & show `TextBox1` and it work but if i try with the row it doesn't work ... is there any way to show/hide `TR` ?

Comment: is the id TempTR unique?

Comment: It works: http://jsfiddle.net/3edjh/

Comment: I updated the code with the real case that generate prblem

Comment: @Hotmoil - Is the extra `'` a posting typo? It shouldn't compile with that in there.

Comment: @Nick not it was mistake from me here and i fix it .. it's not the problem

Comment: Did you inspect the $('#<%= tempTR.ClientID %>') in firebug and compared it with the one of the tr it self?

Comment: @Hotmoil - Is it running in a `document.ready` handler?, e.g. wrapped in `$(function() { $('#<%= tempTR.ClientID %>').hide(); });`?

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the same problem as in this post [JQuery .Show() doesn't work with server control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068923)

Answer (score 1):

If I do this onload it works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tempTR').hide();
});
```

Maybe your problem lies somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the textbox works because it is an asp control and the table row doesn't because it is a HTML element.

Look at the actual HTML and make sure that `$('#<%= tempTR.ClientID %>').hide();` resolves to `$('#tempTR').hide();` in the rendered HTML.

I haven't used ASP in awhile, but I believe it will be render as `$('#tempTR.ClientID')` which isn't an ID in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer, As a you just clicked on an element inside the TR you want to hide, i will use:

```
$('#other').click(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").hide();
});
```

with some effect:

```
$('#other').click(function() {
   $(this).closest("tr").fadeOut('slow');
});
```

remember to put that code in your onready function

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  // Code using $ as usual goes here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not work with a table in Jquery or javascript.  You have to reference a table by class or some other id.  Using element ID does not work with tables.