# JQuery .Show() doesn't work with server control?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, show-hide

I have 2 html TR that i make them `runat="server"` & `visible="false"` and I have a dropdownlist called `citiesDropDownList`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#<%=citiesDropDownList.ClientID %>').change(function() { ValidateCity(); });
});
```

and on change of this dropdownlist i check if the its text equal to a string i show the 2 tr as below

```
function ValidateCity() {
        if ($('#<%= citiesDropDownList.ClientID %> :selected').text() == identity_CityOther)   {
            $('#<%= otherCityTR.ClientID %>').show();
            $('#<%= areasTR.ClientID %>').show();
        }
        var city = $('#<%= citiesDropDownList.ClientID %>').val();
        return IsValid((city.length != 0), '#<%= cityDiv.ClientID %>', identity_CityRequired);
    }
```

.show() isn't work at all and i don't the reason .. can any lead me to get the problem ?

FYI : I tried  `$('#<%= otherCityTR.ClientID %>').show('slow');` and also `$('#<%= otherCityTR.ClientID %>').css('visibility', 'visible');`  but it doesn't work also ...

Comment: have you checked during execution are you getting any errors?

Comment: I have no errors ... just no action !!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`visible="false"` means it doesn't even get rendered into the page, so your selectors aren't finding any elements.

Instead of `visible="false"` use `style="display: none;"` to hide the elements, yet still render them in the page.

Answer (score 3):

If you set `visible = "false"` on a server control, then the control is not even rendered to the browser.  Set `display: none` instead and then show the control with `display: block` in your javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the visible=false from the server control as this stops the control being rendered to the page, either set a CSS style with display: none or hide the required controls in javascript.